# Intersection of Infinite Supersets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need some help to determine if the following statement about sets is indeed true.

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ be sets such that $A_1\supset A_2\supset A_3, ...$. It is true that: $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap\ ... = \emptyset\ $? If it is true, prove it. If it is false, give a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think of $A_n = [0, 1+1/n)$?

Comment: It is valid for finite sets?

Comment: If you're looking to proper superset, then a strictly decreasing sequence can't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If you have a collection where the intersection is zero, add some common new element to all the sets.  What happens then?